# Add in a list collection twice

Tags: c#, .net, list

I'm using a list

```
List<string> mItems = new List<string>();


 mItems = string1.Split(',').ToList();
 mItems = string2.Split(',').ToList();
```

I don't want `string2` to *replace* all items from `string1`. I need to keep `string1` items and *add* `string2` too...

Comment: you can use the AddRange for it

Comment: `foreach`, `AddRange`, `Concat`, what have you tried?

Comment: `mItems.AddRange(string1.Split(',')); mItems.AddRange(string2.Split(','))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use  [AddRange()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.addrange?view=netframework-4.7.2) method, like:

```
mItems = string1.Split(',').ToList();
mItems.AddRange(string2.Split(',').ToList());
```

Comment: You might want to make it clear that you don't need to do `new List<string>()` with your code. Or alternatively use `AddRange` for `string1` too.

Answer (score 3):

When you want to add *several* items (`IEnumerable<T>`) in *one go* just put `AddRange` instead of `Add`:

```
  List<string> mItems = new List<string>();

  ...

  mItems.AddRange(string1.Split(','));
  mItems.AddRange(string2.Split(','));
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use [`Concat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/concatenate-two-sequences) method and LINQ:

```
mItems = string1.Split(',').Concat(string2.Split(',')).ToList();
```

Or just in one line:

```
var mItems = string1.Split(',').Concat(string2.Split(',')).ToList();
```

Just make sure that you have added the following to your using directives:

```
using System.Linq;
```